# Halmos Measure Theory section 39 Theorem D

Tags: integration, measure-theory, transformation

I have trouble explaining the remark "The function $\phi$ plays the role of Jacobian (or, rather, the absolute value of the Jacobian) in the theory of transformation of multiple integrals".

I know the Jacobian determinant in the multiple integrals,
$$\iint_Df(x,y)dxdy=\iint_Df(x(u,v),y(u,v))|J(u,v)|dudv$$

How does the Theorem D relate to the above formula?

Here is the photo from the book.
[image]

Comment: $\mu = \nu = m$, the Lebesque measure, $f = g \circ T$, (hence $g = f \circ T^{-1}$), and $\phi = |\det D T^{-1}|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu=\nu=m$, the Lebesgue measure, $g(y)=g(u,v)$.

Then $\phi=\frac{d(\mu T^{-1})}{d\nu}=\frac{d(mT^{-1})}{dm}$. The function $\phi$ can also be seen roughly as 
$$\phi(y)=\lim_{y\in E,m(E)\rightarrow 0}\frac{mT^{-1}(E)}{m(E)}$$
for $y\in Y$. Obviously, it means the ratio before and after transformation for the aera of the set $E\subset Y$, i.e. the Jacobian determinant.